# How to get the current scroll position in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently, I am working on scroll to top button features.

The button showed up when it is scrollable to bottom. I want to remember the last position when the scroll to top button is clicked. So when the user click the scroll to bottom button , it will return to the last position.

Is there any better idea to retrieve the current scroll position?

`ScrollToTopBottom.vue`

```
<template>

    <div v-if="showScroll" v-scroll="onScroll">
      <v-btn v-if = "!isVisible"
          fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toBottom">
          <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn v-else
          fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toTop">
          <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
    data () {
        return {
        isVisible: false,
        position: 0,
        hasVScroll: false,
    }
  },
   methods: {
    onScroll () {
      this.isVisible = window.scrollY > 500
    },
    toTop () {
      this.position = window.scrollY
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
    toBottom(){
      let pos = this.position > 0 ? this.position : document.body.scrollHeight
      window.scrollTo({
        top: pos,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
    showScroll(){
      this.hasVScroll = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
    }
  }
}

</script>

</script>
```

Comment: hey mate, what do you want to achieve? I didn't understood your question. When you click on top button you go to top of the page, same for bottom you go to bottom of the page.

Comment: uhm how do i explain this ? so like when the user is scrolling down half way of the page , the user clicks the scroll to top button. so when the user reach the top of the page, the user clicks the scroll to bottom button to reach the last position where it clicked the scroll to top button. is that clear enough ?

Comment: tell me if it is not clear , will try again to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your position on top button click, then check it on bottom click:

```js
Vue.component('scrollToTopButton', {
  template: `
    <div v-scroll="onScroll" v-if="hasVerticalScroll">
      <v-btn v-if="!isVisible" fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toBottom">
        <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn v-else fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toTop">
        <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
      position: 0
    }
  },
   methods: {
    onScroll() {
      this.isVisible = window.scrollY > 50
    },
    toTop() {
      this.position = window.scrollY
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
    toBottom(){
      let pos = this.position > 0 ? this.position : document.body.scrollHeight
      window.scrollTo({
        top: pos,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
  },
  computed: {
    hasVerticalScroll(){
      return document.body.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight;
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="demo" >
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>a</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div>
        <scroll-to-top-button />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: could explain this code `let pos = this.position > 0 ? this.position : document.body.scrollHeight` to me ?

Comment: a quick question, how do i hide the scroll to bottom button in the page that does not need to scroll ?

Comment: hmm i tried to disable the button in pages that do not have vertical scroll bar , however it still shows up. I just updated the code. Could you help to point out where i wrong ?

Comment: hey mate, check again I updated my answer